# Java лабораторная на многопоточность

Tags: java, многопоточность, очередь

Создать приложение с 2 параметрами. 1 параметр задает количество cтудентов, 2-ой параметр задает количество преподавателей.
каждый преподаватель строго по очереди приглашает любого студента.
Как только студент получает приглашение , то поток  студент заканчивается. Преподаватель становится после этого последним в очереди преподавателей на вызов студента . 
Потоки - преподаватели должны работать строго по очереди.
Работа продолжается пока есть хоть один студент и если число преподавателей больше нуля.
Использовать ограничения из задания 3. 
Выводить на дисплей имя преподавателя вместе с именем студента.
Выглядеть это будет примерно так: преподаватель1- студент3
                                  преподаватель2- студент1
                                  преподаватель1- студент4
                                  преподаватель2- студент2

Я сижу уже три вечера над этой задачей. Мб кто знает, что взять за разделённую переменную и как организовать классы, чтобы это работало, как просят?

Я думаю, что нужно создать класс Журнал, разделить его объект между потоками студент и преподаватель и записывать в privat string Журнала. Но как организовать параллельную очередь?

UPD:

Я реализовал просто очередь. Она работает не параллельно. Нужно чтобы они выводились не по порядку. А рандомно (из-за работы планировщика)

Class Audience:

```
public class Audience {
    private int amountOfLecturers;
    private int amountOfStudents;
    Queue<Lecturer> lecturers;
    Queue<Student> students;

    public Audience() {
        this.lecturers = new LinkedList<Lecturer>();
        this.students = new LinkedList<Student>();
    }

    public Audience(int amountOfLecturers, int amountOfStudents) {
        this.amountOfLecturers = amountOfLecturers;
        this.amountOfStudents = amountOfStudents;

        this.lecturers = new LinkedList<Lecturer>();
        this.students = new LinkedList<Student>();

        //Assigned name to lecturer
        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfLecturers; i++) {
            Lecturer lect = new Lecturer("Lecturer " + (i + 1));
            lecturers.add(lect);
        }

        //Assigned name to student
        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfStudents; i++) {
            Student stud = new Student("Student " + (i + 1));
            students.add(stud);
        }
    }

    public String queue() {
        String queueStatus = new String();
        Iterator<Student> iter = students.iterator();

        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            lecturers.add(lecturers.element());
            queueStatus =
                    queueStatus +
                    "\n" +
                    lecturers.poll().inviteStudent(students.poll())
            ;
        }

        return queueStatus;
    }
}
```

Class Lecturer:

```
public class Lecturer implements Runnable {

    String name;

    public Lecturer() {

    }

    public Lecturer(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setName(String nameFromOut) {
        this.name = nameFromOut;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String inviteStudent(Student student) {
        String pair;
        pair = this.name + ": " + student.getName();
        return pair;
    }

    public void run() {

    }
}
```

Class Student:

```
public class Student {
    String name;

    public Student() {

    }

    public Student(String nameFromOut) {
        this.name = nameFromOut;
    }

    public void setName(String nameFromOut) {
        this.name = nameFromOut;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите код ваших попыток и подробно объясните, что именно у вас не получилось.

Comment: Я добавил код из предпоследнего варианта. Сейчас я всё целиком переделал. Но оно не работает

Comment: Вообще не понимаю, при чём тут многопоточность...

Comment: @Qwertiy похоже, что два потока/преподавателя должны выгребать из очереди студентов. Но в коде нет ни намёка на попытки создания потоков.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev
Нет. Нужно, чтобы не два, а условное количество преподавателей обрабатывали условное количество студентов. Причём преподаватели тоже в очереди. Насчет намёков и попыток, я написал выше, что не знаю, как организовать многопоточность. Естественно их тут нет

Comment: @Михаил [так](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: @Hivemaster Огромное спасибо! Честно говоря, не думал, что смогу найти ответ на интересующий меня вопрос так быстро. Но вы разрушили всякие сомнения. Теперь-то меня не обмануть, теперь-то я знаааю, что эту работу надо делать, используя ПАРАЛЛЕЛИЗМ!
...Как я до этого сам не догадался? Ума не приложу

Comment: @Михаил чувствую в вашем комментарии иронию, но не понимаю её причин. По ссылке первоисточник кратко, но ёмко описывающий как работать с потоками. Не ждёте же вы, что вам просто напишут решение?

Comment: @Hivemaster Я и не просил решение. Мне нужен совет, как организовать классы. Потому что, прочитав гайд по параллелизму, я могу выполнить это задание как угодно, но не так, как указано в задании.
Ирония к тому, что Вы, даже не читая вопроса, скинули информацию, которую можно найти, загуглив вторую часть заголовка - параллелизм.

Comment: В задании ничего не сказано про то что очередь должна выводиться `рандомно (из-за работы планировщика)` Видимо есть какое-то скрытое требование. Вместо того чтобы выкладывать все задание попробуйте сконцентрироваться на части, которая вызывает проблемы. Попробуйте создать [минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)